# DATEVALUE issue in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, bloomberg

I'm trying to run a simple excel function to compare two dates, however for some reason I get a #VALUE error when using DATEVALUE.

The weird thing is, I do not get this error when I use DATEVALUE for one cell, but I do get it for all other cells.

**I'm not getting this issue for the below.**

```
CELL M:42   -   extracting a date from Bloomberg with function =BDP

CELL L:42   -   =DATEVALUE(M:42)  - gives me datevalue
```

**I get the issue when trying to use =DATEVALUE from any other cell.**

```
CELL M:41   -   11/29/2019
CELL L:41   -   =DATEVALUE(M:41)  - gives me #VALUE error
```

Comment: Is `BDP` function an add-in? Anyway, are you sure that the string you pull into your `DATEVALUE` are actually string values? If they are true dates, it will return an `#VALUE` error.

Comment: Try putting the date in format `dd/mm/yyy` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`. Dates must be like your regional settings

Comment: one, cell references are not `M:42` but `M42`, two what is your local settings for dates: `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`?  If the later it will not be able to convert with DATEVALUE without parsing the string.

Comment: @JvdV yes BDP is a Bloomberg add-in. I didn't know "DATEVALUE" wouldn't work for a true date. I changed them to string values and it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.

I fixed this by taking the date from Cell M:41 and making it a string value.

Comment: Glad it's fixed. Would you really need to use `DATEVALUE` to return the date that you have just converted from a date to a string? It seems haywire to me.